# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child when firing a function

Tags: reactjs

Having an issue firing this function if `this.state.number` is equal to the numbers in the array.

```
  delay = async () => {
     const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
     await sleep(1000);
     return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
  }
```

error

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children,
>   use an array instead.

**Home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import './App.css';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Home extends Component {

    state = {
        number: "",

        numbers: ["111-111-1112, 111-111-1111, 111-111-1116, 111-111-1118"]
      };


      onChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
          number: e.target.value
        });
      };

      delay = async () => {
        const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
        await sleep(1000);
        return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
      }

      validate = myNum => this.state.numbers.find(num => num === myNum);
      render(){

        const validatedNumber = (
          <div>
            <span style={{ color: "green" }}>Activated ✅ </span>
            {this.delay()}
          </div>
        );
        return (
          <div className="main">
             <Grid container >
               <Grid item sm={8} md={12} >
                <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Validate Number"
                value={this.state.number}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                />
            <h2>
              {this.validate(this.state.number) ? (
                validatedNumber
              ) : (
                <div>Not in the system</div>
              )}
            </h2>

               </Grid>   

             </Grid>

          </div>
        );

      }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: you cannot "render" a promise. Instead of doing it that way, you should call that method outside of the return/jsx. set a state variable when the timer is done. and render redirect from that state variable

Comment: Or you could programmatically redirect at the end of a timeout.

Comment: @AvinKavish true, but since the op is using `react-router-dom` the convention is to render a redirect. Either would work tho :)

Comment: John would you be able to provide an answer showing how you would do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this error beucase `this.delay()` will return a `Promise` object and you can't render objects.

Any function that have `async` returns a `Promise`.

To solve this, you need a `if` to decide what to return and a state to keep the `status` of the `setTimeout`.

1. **Keep a state of `shouldRedirect`**

   ```
   state = {
      ...
      shouldRedirect: false
   }
   ```
2. **Update the state when the `setTimeout` finishes**

   ```
   delay = async () => {
       const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
       await sleep(1000);
       this.setState({shouldRedirect: true})
   }
   ```
3. **Check in the render method if `shouldRedirect`**

   ```
   render(){
       if(this.state.shouldRedirect){
           return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
       }
       // continue with normal render
       ...
   }
   ```
4. **Call `delay` in the correct place**

   ```
   onChange = e => {
       e.preventDefault();
       let number = e.target.value
       this.setState({number});
       if(this.state.numbers.find(num => num === number)){
           this.delay()
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: It might be simpler option to use `withRouter` and then `this.props.history.push("/dashboard")`.

Comment: @AnttiPihlaja Yes, that is much better! But because the OP is using `<Redirect />` I provided the answer using that.

Comment: one piece of puzzle missing here, `delay` needs to be called from somewhere, it cannot be from `render` (because of `this.setState`), so some life cycle method, e.g. `componentDidMount`

Comment: thank you for the solution, but the delay function should fire only if a number is === to a number within the array, as of now it just fires without checking the data.

Comment: it has to happen post validation

Comment: @BARNOWL i added the way to call it so it keeps the same functionality :)

Comment: @BARNOWL Now I think is in the way you want. Please check it out

Comment: @BARNOWL did you remove the original call `{this.delay()}` when moving it to `onChange`?

Comment: @BARNOWL what doesn't work? please be more especific

Comment: Vencovsky, setstate is async. you cant check its value like that

Comment: @JohnRuddell I'm checking `numbers` not `number`. There is two different things.

Comment: It works now thanks for the explanation and the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to capture the value of the event before passing it to `setState` or else the event might go out of scope before state is set.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import './App.css';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        number: "",
        numbers: ["111-111-1112, 111-111-1111, 111-111-1116, 111-111-1118"],
        isValid: false
      };

      onChange = e => {
        const number = e.target.value
        this.setState({ number });
        if (this.isValid(number)) {
          setTimeout(() => this.props.history.push('/dashboard'), 1000)
          this.setState({ isValid: true })
        }
      };

      isValid = myNum => this.state.numbers.find(num => num === myNum);

       render() {
        const { number, isValid } = this.state
        return (
          <div className="main">
             <Grid container >
               <Grid item sm={8} md={12} >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Validate Number"
                  value={number}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                <h2>
                 {isValid ? (
                  <div>
                    <span style={{ color: "green" }}>Activated ✅ </span>
                  </div>
                 ) 
                 : (
                   <div>Not in the system</div>
                )}
              </h2>
            </Grid>   
          </Grid>
        </div>
       );
     }
}
export default withRouter(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an right way, but if you want, you can do something weird:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      asyncjsx: null
    };
  }

  delay = async () => {
    const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    await sleep(3000);
    return <div>second</div>;
  };

  render() {
    (async () => {
      this.setState({ asyncjsx: await this.delay() });
    })();

    return (
      <>
        <div>first</div>
        {this.state.asyncjsx && this.state.asyncjsx}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```